# Set UIToolBar Vertical setup with StoryBoards

Tags: swift, ios8, uistoryboard, uitoolbar

I currently have an app with a square UIView where an image will be drawn. In Portrait view a UIToolBar exists at the bottom of the UIViewController.

It looks like this :

[image]

However, when changing into landscape mode,I'd like the view to stay a square on the left hand side, and the toolbar to be aligned vertically on the right hand side, and the icons stacked vertically. Is there a way to do this with Storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in storyboard as standard UIToolBar does not support vertical layout. You will need to develop your own component or find something third-party.